# Ruby / Rails syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How does this syntax work?

```
before_validation { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
```

I would think that it would need to be this:

```
before_validation { |user| user.email = user.email.downcase }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It work because

```
before_validation { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
```

SAME AS

```
before_validation { |user| user.email = self.email.downcase }
```

Comment: Thanks! So the `self` is implied?

Comment: == the context passed is the user

Answer (score -1):

It works, but keep the DRY principle of Ruby. This would be better:

```
before_validation { |user| user.email.downcase! }
```

`!` reflects the changes back onto the receiving object and it also saves a few keystrokes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He is asking *how* his code works. He is not asking for alternative syntax.